# CS193P SwiftUI 2020 Assignment 3 - Closure as a function parameter

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, closures

I'm following Paul Hegarty's CS193P 2020 course and the assignment 3 asks us to use a closure as a parameter for a function. That's something we already did in a previous lecture and it was quite clear for me (in fact I thought it was).
After trying by myself I finally found the solution here: https://github.com/marlen-myn/set-game and it works fine but I still have difficulties to understand what's happening.

Here is the Model code with the SetGame init using a closure to create the CardContent.

```
struct SetGame {
    var deck: [Card]
    
    init(cardContentFactory: (Int, CardShape, CardShading, CardColor) -> CardContent) {
        deck = [Card]()
        for number in 1...3 {
            for shape in CardShape.allCases {
                for shading in CardShading.allCases {
                    for color in CardColor.allCases {
                        let content = cardContentFactory(number, shape, shading, color)
                        deck.append(Card(id: deck.count, content: content))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel :

```
class SetGameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var setModel: SetGame
    
    init() {
        setModel = SetGame() {
            CardContent(number: $0, shape: $1, shading: $2, color: $3)
        }
        print(setModel.deck)
    }
}
```

I have two questions regarding this code:

- I don't understand how the line `CardContent(number: $0, shape: $1, shading: $2, color: $3)` works since it seems to me it doesn't pass any "actual" data. In the previous lecture the example Paul used was transmitting real data. Here is the code used and it clearly passes the surfer emoji

  ```
   func createMemoryGame() -> MemoryGame<String> {
   return MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairsOfCards: 2) { _ in "‍♂️" }}
  ```
- It seems to me that there is no real need to do this this way (with a closure). Is it because it's not done right (even if it works) or because it is really useless.

Thank you for your help, I really want to understand this because I know closures are everywhere in Swift and also because I hate doing something I don't understand even if it works.

Comment: in the second set of code `_ in` ignores the data returned into the closure. Replace the underscore with `value` and you can now read it if you remove it all together you can read it with `$0`. the $0, $1, etc are the return values in the order without actually defining them `SetGame() { (number, shape, shading, color) in` would actually define the return values and you can replace the respective `$n` in the `CardContent` `init`

Comment: Thank you, I’m going to test the other way to do it with the SetGame() { (number, shape, shading, color) } in  and turning values. It seems to me it is more in line with the generic approach and the respective role of Model and ViewModel.

Comment: Don't put the closing bracket at the end of that line. The closure finishes after the `CardContent` `init` whatever you need to do has to be between those brackets and ultimately `return CardContent(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I finally understand. Going to check it in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
        setModel = SetGame() {
        CardContent(number: $0, shape: $1, shading: $2, color: $3)
    }
```

So here we're using a trailing closure. Instead you could write it as:

```
SetGame.init(cardContentFactory: { CardContent(number: $0, shape: $1, shading: $2, color: $3) } )
```

So we are passing data in, to the SetGame.init(cardContentFactory:) method: we're passing a closure that, later on, takes in values for the 4 params.

On `$0`, `$1`, `$2` - these represent pronouns, the arguments into the function. The reason these are useful is to be concise: for example, consider this playground:

```
func changeThings(how f: (String) -> String) -> [String] {
    let things: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

    var result: [String] = []
    for thing in things {
        result.append(f(thing))
    }
    return result
}

let lc1 = changeThings(how: { string in return string.lowercased() })
let lc2 = changeThings(how: { $0.lowercased() })

func doubleString(_ s: String) -> String {
    return "\(s)\(s)"
}

let db1 = changeThings(how: doubleString(_:))
let db2 = changeThings(how: { "\($0)\($0)" })
```

Here `{ string in return string.lowercased() }` is a long way of saying "lowercase it", and so `$0` means "it". $1, $2 etc for the second, third arguments. Similarly having to create and name functions (like `doubleString(_:)` is long way of just using anonymous (unnamed) closures.

Comment: For my understanding, we can pass the value directly with the closure or use the $x to manage the value later?

Comment: What you are passing is a function, aka a closure, in to the SetGame.init(cardContentFactory:) method, and that makes you a new SetGame with this function baked into it. Now any time the SetGame wants to make a new card, it uses this function to make that card's contents. $0, $1 etc represent the values being passed from SetGame into the 'card content factory' function when it calls the function to make a new card

Comment: The reason why this function is an argument to SetGame is so that you can change it. You can pass in some other function to make a different kind of SetGame, that still uses the same logic of SetGame, but makes cards with different contents whenever it makes cards

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, it starts to make sense to me. And it’s a big step as it is a fundamental aspect of Swift.